# Typescript type guards for string union types without repetition

Tags: typescript

I receive a Typescript error that `string` is not of type `'food' | 'drink' | other`, when I do:

```
order = x
```

Because Typescript assumes that `x` can be any string, and not just `'food' | 'drink' | other`, so it throws an error.

Of course, I can get rid of this error if I put my code inside the type guard like this:

```
const order = 'food' // default value
if (x === 'food' || x === 'drink' || x === 'other') {
 order = x
}
```

I just wonder, can I make this code shorter, DRY and non-repetitive?

Just to let you know, putting the strings in an array `['food', 'drink', 'other']` and doing the condition `if (array.includes(x)) {order = x}`, doesn't do the trick!

Comment: What does the declaration or assignment of `x` look like?

Comment: x is the string value I get from the API.

Comment: is x a fixed set of strings? otherwise, there is no way typescript can infer it.

Comment: Yes, API can return only this 3 values for x - 'food', 'drink', 'other'.

Comment: Do you have a type declaration for the results from the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [type predicate function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to cast this to the correct type:

```
function isMember<T extends string>(
  array: readonly T[],
  value: string
): value is T {
  return (array as readonly string[]).includes(value)
}
```

This accepts an array, and a value. The member type of the array is captured as the generic parameter `T`. The return value is `value is T`, which means that if `true` is returned, than the variable passed as `value` will be considered a `T`, and if false is returned then it will be treated as the type of the argument `string`.

Which you could use like so:

```
const x: string = 'drink'
let order: 'food' | 'drink' | 'other' = 'food' // default value

if (isMember(['food', 'drink', 'other'], x)) {
    order = x // x is of type: 'food' | 'drink' | 'other'
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6&jsx=0&module=1&ssl=8&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=2#code/FDBmFcDsGMBcEsD2kAE8DOBZApgWwEbYBOAPACorYAes2kAJuiurEfJAOYB8AFAIZEifAJ4AuFGQDaAXQA0KAG58ANuGziWbTgEpxS1djRMKAb2AoLKItljgiqfoJEo+TTew4ztAOnbRV9NjoPPpq2sAAviDA0MgsKFQarB4oALwoAOT0WgDWGcDKNiiIRIFE4hmgiIj0GSgAPpnZ7HkNmYiwABbEdemV1bUoAPRDKIGgfODKsIoqaiDwoCg8GDgExDyS-TUZ8lm5u+1dPXIJ2tooZpbFpcRpCcOjVEbFS7DCAA7qmVU7bfstOqNDIdbpEfIRIA)

---

Now to clean this up a bit, you can setup your type and constants like so:

```
const yummyStrings = ['food', 'drink', 'other'] as const
type YummyString = (typeof yummyStrings)[number] // 'food' | 'drink' | 'other'
```

And use those like this:

```
const x: string = 'drink'
let order: YummyString = 'food' // default value

if (isMember(yummyStrings, x)) {
    order = x // x is of type: 'food' | 'drink' | 'other'
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6&jsx=0&module=1&ssl=8&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=2#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAzgWQKYFsBGGBOAPACqIYAeUGYAJioilPjGAOYB8AFAIb77cBPAFyJ8GbjQQAbAYmIBtALoAaRADduUkBhGNmbAJQiNWjMnqkA3gChEd0Righ8SHn0GJu9MROmy9LKxKBgB0LBBaNBgonCbaBtYAvtbWEAiMiAIgWFgCAMpMgfQAvIjyAOTAcHA05arlNPoA1nWI5XBQABYE5Yqe9GlgjNZQAgAOZgCa2bkF+qyIpZyjE3DAmTP5hWwoBvJg2Xj4iimDGeS62wulDc3l1lKOiHD4Ufgi0zlb84ttVTXlRAAeiBiCiwG4ICkUHUmm0KRg604qEwuAInCyXzmRVU5AMBkQNnsz1eBF+5GBoIpqGe6xWOj+1VqiAAPm1GiwWqy2h1uvh7okgA)

Comment: Yeah I was looking at [this code](https://tsplay.dev/wOJREW). `includes()` doesn't already behave this way for the reasons outlined in https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26255 and https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36275.

Comment: I do not doubt that this solution works, but it is more complicated than simple: if (x === 'food' || x === 'drink' || x === 'other') {
 order = x
}

Comment: Properly type narrowing from untyped data sources like parsed JSON is not a simple task, sadly. But the "right" solution here depends on how many places you want to do this, and how many possible members there are, and how often that list will be updated. If you answered "a lot" to any of those, than a robust "complicated" solution will probably serve you best.

Comment: @Manzana am I to understand that the only solution you'll accept must be shorter than 46 characters? Given that the functionality does not already exist in the language, and that you'd have to build it first in order to use it, I think there's probably nothing you'll accept, at least until you have to write `x ===` tests in more places in your code base.

Comment: An analogy, possibly... Person A: Is there some simpler, less repetitive way to add these numbers together? `let s = 8 + 6 + 7 + 5 + 3 + 0 + 9;` Person B: you could write `let s = [8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9].reduce((a, x) => x + a);` Person A: well, that's less repetitive but it's longer and more complicated than the simple version I started with.  Person B: ‍♂️

Comment: The real point, I suppose, is that `isMember(yummyStrings, x)` is "shorter, DRY and non-repetitive" when compared to `x === 'food' || x === 'drink' || x === 'other'`

Comment: Don't get me wrong. Alex Wayne answer is a good solution and I accepted it as the right answer.

Comment: Alex Wayne solution is way superior that the "peasant" type guard method that I introduced in my question. And it will be better solution in 99% of the cases, except the isolated cases with small (1-3) number of conditions.